# What is actually an INT_PTR and how can I convert data to INT_PTR?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to use the `TBBUTTON` structure that Windows API provides for creating toolbar buttons. Of course I tried adding some text to those buttons, so I set the `iString` member of `TBBUTTON` structure, which is of type `INT_PTR`:

```
typedef struct {
  int       iBitmap;
  int       idCommand;
  BYTE      fsState;
  BYTE      fsStyle;
#ifdef _WIN64
  BYTE      bReserved[6];
#else 
#if defined(_WIN32)
  BYTE      bReserved[2];
#endif 
#endif 
  DWORD_PTR dwData;
  INT_PTR   iString;
} TBBUTTON, *PTBBUTTON, *LPTBBUTTON;
```

There is an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298381(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN which initializes that structure like this:

```
TBBUTTON tbButton = { MAKELONG(STD_FILENEW,  ImageListID), IDM_NEW,  TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"New" };
```

Notice the `(INT_PTR)L"File"` conversion there. When I do the exact same thing, I get some strange strings displayed:

[image]

I read the documentation about `INT_PTR` on MSDN, but I still don't understand it, because somehow, it works for them but not for me...

So how to convert that Unicode string to `INT_PTR`?

Comment: _"What is actually an `INT_PTR`?"_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented on MSDN under MFC. The Toolbar class is technically not part of the Windows API (Win32), but actually MFC. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdabdzxd.aspx

It says:

> `iString`
>
> Zero-based index of the string to use as the button's label, `-1` if there is no string for this button. The image and/or string whose index you provide must have previously been added to the toolbar control's list using `AddBitmap`, `AddString`, and/or `AddStrings`.

So casting a string isn't going to work (and in C++ always prefer C++-style casting operators over C-style casts).

`AddString` itself [expects a Resource ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkz6w6k6.aspx) rather than a string literal. Use `AddStrings` to use in-memory strings.

So your code should look like this (pseudocodeish):

```
LPCTSTR buttonTexts = L"Button1\0Button2\0"; // single buffer containing multiple null-terminated strings, and must end with two \0 (note the last null is implicit).

CToolbarCtrl* toolbar = ...
int addStringResult = toolbar->AddStrings( buttonTexts );
if( addStringResult == -1 ) die();

TBBUTTON buttons[] = {
    { /* ... */ iString: 0 },
    { /* ... */ iString: 1 }
};
BOOL addButtonResult = toolbar->AddButtons( 2, &buttons );
if( !addButtonResult ) die();
```

Comment: In my code, I am creating kind of a hook. I need to get the string value for every top-level menu in `IDR_MENU` resource. And then label the toolbar using those strings. I am doing something like: loop through menus from that resource and doing `menu.GetMenuString(i, cstringValues[i], MF_BYPOSITION);`. Do I have to make those transformations to add the `null` character after each string for using `AddStrings`?

Comment: Could you join me here, please? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/91283/create-menu-like-toolbar-in-mfc?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

`INT_PTR` is a type that is an integer but which has the guarantee that it has the size of a pointer. Using `reinterpret_cast`, you can convert between a pointer type and `INT_PTR`.

Now, concerning you question about a Unicode string, I don't know, because I don't know what representation of that string you have. You'll have to provide more info for that.